# Save json dictionary to core data Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data, swifty-json

I am able to get the last guest dictionary value in the json array saved into core data as a dictionary using the transformable key value however the other guest dictionary values are not saving. Guest is also it's on entity for now but I was hoping to save the guest as a dictionary since this task doesn't require complex relationships. I'm sure I'm looking through the json, the value type for reservation.guest = `[AnyHashable: Any]?`Any suggestions would be helpful here is my json response https://pastebin.com/J28myW66, thanks

Note: using Alamofire for the HTTP Request. Also haven't included my entire class here as this is the main part of it. Reservation and Guest are both NSManagedObject classes

```
    let managedObjectContext = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let reservationEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Reservation", in: managedObjectContext)
    let guestEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Guest", in: managedObjectContext)

    let reservation = Reservation(entity: reservationEntityDescription!, insertInto: managedObjectContext)
    let guest = Guest(entity: guestEntityDescription!, insertInto: managedObjectContext)


    let url = "\(serverEndpoint)\(path)"

    manager?.request(
        url
        ).responseJSON { responseData in

            if(responseData.result.error != nil) {

                print(responseData.response)
            }
            else if responseData.result.value != nil{


                let json = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

               let content = json["data"]

                    var reservationArray: [String] = []
                    if let dates = content.array {
                        for item in dates {
                            if let str = item["date_time"].string {
                                reservationArray.append(str)
                                print(reservationArray)
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    for (key,obj) in content {

                        let guestData = obj["guest"]
                        let guestDict = guestData.dictionaryObject!

                        reservation.guest = guestDict
                        reservation.id = obj["id"].stringValue
                        reservation.dateTime = obj["date_time"].date
                        reservation.startTime = obj["start_time"].time 
                        reservation.numOfPeople = obj["number_of_people"].intValue as NSNumber?
                        reservation.status = obj["status"].stringValue
                        reservation.tables = obj["tables"].arrayObject as! [NSString]?
                        reservation.reservationCollections = reservationArray as [NSString]?

                        guest.id = guestData["id"].stringValue
                        guest.email = guestData["email"].stringValue
                        guest.name = guestData["full_name"].stringValue
                        guest.phone = guestData["phone"].stringValue
                        guest.notes = guestData["notes"].stringValue

                    }
                     print("Reservation to be saved\(reservation)")
                     print("Guest to be saved: \(guest)")
             }
       }

               do {
                    try reservation.managedObjectContext?.save()

                    } catch let error as NSError {

                        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)

                    }

                do {
                    try guest.managedObjectContext?.save()

                } catch let error as NSError {

                    fatalError(error.localizedDescription)

                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your code starts, you create **one** instance of `Guest` and **one** instance of `Reservation`:

```
let reservation = Reservation(entity: reservationEntityDescription!, insertInto: managedObjectContext)
let guest = Guest(entity: guestEntityDescription!, insertInto: managedObjectContext)
```

After that you never create any other instances. In your loop you assign values to this instance:

```
reservation.guest = guestDict
reservation.id = obj["id"].stringValue
...

guest.id = guestData["id"].stringValue
guest.email = guestData["email"].stringValue
...
```

But since there's only one instance, only the last pass through the loop gets saved. The first time through the loop you assign values to `guest` and `reservation`. Every other time, you overwrite the previous values with new ones.

If you want to save a new instance for every pass through the loop, you need to create new instances every time. Move the `let guest = ...` and `let reservation = ...` lines inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you and nice explanation. Can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to make design flow bit generic i.e The HTTP request/response, DataBase Part, Model Part and UI part.

Now create a generic model class for your response, 
so that the values will bind in single object.
In you core data sub class your table i.e custom `NSManagedObject` Class.

First convert the dictionary objects [objects in `content.array`] into respective model class objects.

In that `SBPlayer` is a model class

`Favourite+CoreDataProperties.swift` & `Favourite+CoreDataClass.swift` are custom `NSManagedObject` class (auto-generated).

Now with every object, you have mapping respective properties in database table and in custom `NSManagedObject` class.

Map the values and Save it DataBase.

**For example:** https://github.com/Abhishek9634/ScoreBoard/blob/master/ScoreBoard/ScoreBoard/SBDBManager.swift

**Reference** : https://github.com/Abhishek9634/ScoreBoard